# Cannot delete gke instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Gke has been struggling for nearly a month to delete a node and the instance seems to somehow be in limbo. I am unable to suspend, stop or delete it.
It returns variations of the same error regardless how i try to get rid of it.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - Too many pending operations on a resource.
```

LE: Log explorer shows

```
Instance Group Manager 'projects/xxx/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-standard-cluster-spot-4core-16ram-xxxxx' initiated deleteInstance on instance 'projects/xxxx/zones/us-central1-a/instances/gke-standard-cluster-spot-4core-16ram-xxxx'. Reason: need to continue current process.
```

Is anyone able to give me a tip on how to get rid of it? It pretty much messed up the autoscaler, since from its perspective there's a new node about to be spawned (though it's been trying that since Nov 23)

Comment: Try with this [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/target-pools/remove-instances)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your instance group size. If you have many instance group.

If you just run GCLOUD COMPUTE INSTANCE DELETE it wont work.

If you delete one of the machines, GCE will start a new one. you have to use the gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances command, followed by gcloud compute instance-groups managed wait-until-stable.